# InputStream and Jersey Java Rest client Issue

Tags: java, rest, web, jersey, inputstream

Is it possible to open an input stream and send that on the output response of a restful webservice done with the Jersey API? I'm trying to stream a file to another resource using the Jersey client and Java and wondering if this is possible?

Comment: I think this might be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/a/12251265/12060 - does that answer help with your issue?