# REST - How to expose a file in a file repository project?

Tags: java, rest

I am writing project which is simple web file repository. A client sends me a file with `POST`:

```
POST /file
<binary data>
```

and gets `hash` of the file as a response.

He can send images, documents, etc. I would like to provide him a best way to retrieve those files from the application with hashes. So he could call:

```
GET /file/{hash}
```

And retrieve `binary` version of file.

Or maybe the better approach is to give him the file properties like:

```
{
    type: "image/png"
    bytes: 1024,
    properties: [{
        width: 100,
        height: 200
    }]
}
```

And then under URLs:

```
GET /file/{hash}?base64
```

He will get Base64 encoded file, and under

```
GET /file/{hash}?binary
```

will be binary version of file responded? Which approach is better and more RESTful?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12239868/whats-the-correct-way-to-send-a-file-from-rest-web-service-to-client this might help

Answer (score 2):

I think it's up to your needs. I will go with the former if you don't need the extra file properties.

By the way, maybe you will find inspiring to take a look to Google Drive API:
https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/

Answer (score 2):

Theoretically when you send response to `POST` method you should return an `ID`, along with the body you received and `201 Created` HTTP status code. Of course it doesn't make sense at all in this particular case. So:

1. The response to `POST` request should be marked with `301 Moved Permanently` and have `Location` (e.g. `/files/{hash}` header set which points to an endpoint where client can get files data.
2. If client requests to URL from mentioned `Location` header it may receive a JSON content with basic file description (size, content type, hash, whatever is needed)
3. A separate endpoint (e.g. `/files/{hash}/data/`) should be provided to return files raw data. Client also should have a possibility to set a data format it would like to get but not via query parameter name only (`?binary`, `?base64`) but with key-value pair. (`?format=binary`).