# ResponseEntity<byte[]> send String through Rest web service

Tags: java, arrays, string, rest, web-services

I'm using Spring and Rest web service and I have a problem with `byte array` and `String`. I have to send a String in my ResponseEntity and on the client I have to retrieve the original String. I can't use `ResponseEntity<String>` because I need to send file. 
This is part of my web services that send `String` or file:

```
@Override
@RequestMapping(value = "/file", method = RequestMethod.GET) 
    public  ResponseEntity<byte[]> getAcquisition(HttpServletResponse resp,@RequestParam(value="filePath", required = true) String filePath){
        final HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        OutputStream outputStream = null;
        File toServeUp= null;
        try{
            toServeUp=new File(filePath);
            if (!toServeUp.exists()){
                headers.setContentType(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN);
                LOG.error("Threw exception in MatlabClientControllerImpl::getAcquisition : File doesn't exists!!");
                String message = "ERROR: Could not retrieve file on server, check the path!";       
                return new ResponseEntity<byte[]>(message.getBytes(("UTF-8")), headers, HttpStatus.OK);
.....
```

On the client I use this method:

```
@Override
    public Response getFile(String serverIp, String toStorePath, String filePath){
        ResponseEntity<byte[]> responseEntity = null;
        try{
            RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
            responseEntity  = restTemplate.getForEntity(serverIp + "ATS/client/file/?filePath={filePath}", byte[].class, filePath); 

            if (MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN.toString().equals(responseEntity.getHeaders().getContentType().toString()))
                return new Response(false, false, new String(responseEntity.getBody(),"UTF-8"), null);
....
```

This is an example of response:

```
{
  "status": false,
  "success": false,
  "result": "IlJWSlNUMUk2SUVWeWNtOXlJR2x1SUhSb1pTQndZWFJvTENCamFHVmpheUJwZENFPSI=",
  "error": null
}
```

But I retrieve several characters but not those I had sent through the server.
I have tried a lot of alternatives but none works.
Do you have any idea? Thanks

Comment: Did you tried?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12239868/whats-the-correct-way-to-send-a-file-from-rest-web-service-to-client

Comment: Yes, I saw it. I spent about three day to find one code that works with download and upload file and ResponseEntity allow it. Response is a my class not the default 'Response'

Comment: Usually it would be like  files bytes converted to base64. Did you try decoding from base64 and write those bytes in  file and check contents.

Comment: If I use new String(Base64.decodeBase64(responseEntity.getBody()),Charset.forName("UTF-8")) it works. Many thanks. Add The response so I can set as true