# File is not getting download using JERSEY

Tags: java, download, httpresponse, jersey-2.0, jersey-client

I am using jersey API in my project. I stuck in a case that file needs to be downloaded but it's not. My code is as follow

```
@GET
@Produces("application/download")
public Response downloadFile(){ 
    String data = getDatas();
    ResponseBuilder response = Response.ok(data);
    response.header("Content-Disposition","attachment;filename=UserData.txt");
    response.header("charset", "UTF-8");
    return Response.build(); 
}
```

I have added all the packages, paths are also fine. No Error came.

When I call this API, data comes in the response. I want this data to be in a file and in a downloadable format.

I also tried `@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM)`.

Please correct me if am doing wrong

Comment: possible duplicate, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12239868/whats-the-correct-way-to-send-a-file-from-rest-web-service-to-client

Answer (score 0):

I think you are not sending the response you have build.

first you're using a ResponseBuilder to build the resposne

```
ResponseBuilder response = Response.ok(data);
response.header("Content-Disposition","attachment;filename=UserData.txt");
response.header("charset", "UTF-8");
```

then you are returning the static `Response.build()` (notice the capital `R`) object, which is empty

you should return `response.build()`

also, you should produce `octet-stream` in your method annotions

```
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM)
```

and not

```
@Produces("application/download")
```

refer to this question: [what's the correct way to send a file from REST web service to client?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12239868/whats-the-correct-way-to-send-a-file-from-rest-web-service-to-client)

Comment: i have used response.build() only. it was a typo error and also i have tried using @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM). It's not getting download