# send a file from the server side to the client side using rest service

Tags: java, spring, rest, file, spring-mvc

I want to send a file from the server side to the client side using rest service 
I'm using spring MVC. I used this service method:

```
public ResponseEntity<InputStreamResource> postFile() throws Exception {


    DocumentDaoImpl dao = new DocumentDaoImpl();

    Document docCmis = (Document) dao.getDocument("workspace://SpacesStore/ae6d1722-0f08-49ab-a73b-c07036001318");
    byte[] myByteArray = readContent(docCmis.getContentStream().getStream());


    ClassPathResource myFile = new ClassPathResource(docCmis.getContentStreamFileName());
    //System.out.println("eeeee"+pdfFile);

    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.add("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate");
    headers.add("Pragma", "no-cache");
    headers.add("Expires", "0");
    return ResponseEntity
            .ok()
            .headers(headers)
            .contentLength(myByteArray.length)
            .contentType(MediaType.parseMediaType("application/octet-stream"))
            .body(new InputStreamResource(docCmis.getContentStream().getStream()));


}
```

and this function in a rest controller class

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/downloadPDFFile",produces = { "application/json" }, method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public ResponseEntity downloadPDFFile() throws Exception {
    return courriersArrivésServices.postFile();

}
```

then with a rest call using RestTemplate class,i tryied to get my file

```
Map<String, Object> selectedCourrier=restTemplate.getForObject(SERVER_URI + "/getCourrierDetails"+"?id="+id, HashMap.class);
```

But that didn't work for me and gives me this error

```
org.springframework.web.client.RestClientException: Could not extract response: no suitable HttpMessageConverter found for response type [class org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity] and content type [application/octet-stream]
```

Comment: Please, provide code with your controller class, and show what actualy doesn't work.

Comment: Please check if this question can help you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12239868/whats-the-correct-way-to-send-a-file-from-rest-web-service-to-client

Comment: You can follow this https://www.leveluplunch.com/java/tutorials/032-return-file-from-spring-rest-webservice/

Comment: @Optio I edited my answer

Comment: @AliakseiStadnik I used that tutorial but doesn't still don't work ,I have just edited my question with the logs that the program gives me when using that tuto

Comment: Try to return ResponseEntity<byte[]>

Comment: no didn't work for me

Comment: @WassimMakni try add additional message converter to your rest template. RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(new ByteArrayHttpMessageConverter());
See last screenshot here https://www.leveluplunch.com/java/tutorials/038-retrieve-file-spring-resttemplate/

Answer (score 0):

### Server side:

```
@RequestMapping("/download")
public byte[] download() throws Exception {
    File f = new File("C:\\WorkSpace\\Text\\myDoc.txt");
    byte[] byteArray = new byte[(int) f.length()];
    byteArray = FileUtils.readFileToByteArray(f);
    return byteArray;
}
```

### Client side:

```
private ResponseEntity<byte[]> getDownload(){
    URI end = URI.create("http://vmvdi05059:8080/ePaymentsWeb/download");
    return rest.getForEntity(end,byte[].class);

}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    byte[] byteArray = new TestClient().getDownload().getBody();
    FileOutputStream fos = new 
    FileOutputStream("C:\\WorkSpace\\testClient\\abc.txt");

    fos.write(byteArray);
    fos.close(); 
    System.out.println("file written successfully..");

 }
```