# How to import products from resource server into Hybris

Tags: java, rest, api, web-services, sap-commerce-cloud

How to create a web service that will get xml file with products from resource server and import it into Hybris Commerce?

Answer (score 0):

I prefer using cronjob, because of performance issues.

**Step one:**

You can get xml file with rest using this example https://stackoverflow.com/a/12251265/2847159 and save it as media or temporarily.

**Step two:**

Create new cronjob which process that xml file and convert it to impex file.

**Step three:**

Start OOTB impex import cron job for processing new impex.

**NOTE**: If xml file little, you can directly start impex import cron job in rest service.

Answer (score 0):

If interested, you can check `bmecat` extension.

https://help.hybris.com/6.5.0/hcd/8b6c475086691014815cd5174177294d.html