# Best way to send file from java server to client

Tags: jquery, ajax, hibernate, spring-mvc, jackson

I uploaded an image successfully in MYSQL database using spring MVC(MultipartFile) and hibernate.
now I want to get it from db and set it in my page with ajax request and my request is done successfully .(server response is ok)

but the server(java) **sends me the image in form of base64 URL string.**
So my question is :

**base 64 URL is big string and so performance will be affected by it**
 , is there any other way to send the image from server to client without encoded to BASE64 URL ?

*I use Jackson library for my response .*
Thank you .

Comment: is there any problem sending it as MultipartFile itself ? let spring use appropriate http message converters to write to the body

Comment: Can i send files from **server** to  **client** as Multipart Files  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put your image into some `Resource` (probably `ByteArrayResource` containing bitmap) and then return it.

As described here: [file downloading in restful web services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10100936/file-downloading-in-restful-web-services)

But I am not sure that it's more convenient way from frontend prespective.

Comment: Thank you . I was looking for best format for reponse instead of Base64URL  .