# How to fix rest get, file download showing sometimes file not found error

Tags: java, rest, jax-rs

So I'm trying to download a file that I upload before, using a rest get method but sometimes I get file not found error and other times it just works. I don't know where the problem is.

I also tried the code that is in this thread [file downloading in restful web services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10100936/file-downloading-in-restful-web-services) and changed it a little but the problem with this code is that I don't see the contents of the files so my solution is a little better I think.

```
@GET
  @Path("/{fileName}")
  @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM)
  public Response downloadFile(@PathParam("fileName") String fileName) throws IOException
  {
    File ivyFile = new File(fileName);
    byte[] data = ivyFile.readBinary().toByteArray();
    StreamingOutput fileStream = new StreamingOutput()
      {
        @Override
        public void write(java.io.OutputStream output)
        {
          try
          {
            output.write(data);
            output.flush();
          }
          catch (IOException e)
          {
            throw new WebApplicationException("Could not Find the file: '" + fileName + "'", e);
          }
        }
      };
    return Response.ok(fileStream, MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM)
            .header("content-disposition", "attachment; filename = " + fileName).build();
  }
```

I expect to download the file with the content and be able to see it.

EDIT:
Also I get response 200 when this error occures. And this error as well:

```
MalformedChunkCodingException: CRLF expected at end of chunk
    FacesException: org.apache.http.MalformedChunkCodingException: CRLF expected at end of chunk
    Error during rendering of html dialog 'com.axonivy.connectivity.rest.FileUpload'
```

Comment: Can you just do output.write("Hello World") and see if you can get it in the downloaded file.

Comment: @Ganeshchaitanya I can't put a string into OutputStream

Comment: but you can String.getBytes and put that into output stream cant you?

Comment: @Antoniossss Oh yeah thats true. So when I put The string in the output.write It is in the File. But again I had to try and download it a few times because it shows that the file is not found

Comment: Try 

builder#entity(new ByteArrayEntity(yourData)); so exception handling might be preserved./

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. The problem was with my IDE that was causing a timeout for the download.